# How to change the favicon dynamically in VueJs

Tags: vue.js, favicon

I would like to do this very common trick that is to be able to change the favicon of my VueJs app dynamically.

For example : I have a timer in my app that is running in background and I would like to change the favicon when the timer is running.

In VueJs since the favicon is set in the index.html file I really don't know how could I do to be able to modify it in others component of my app. ?

I tried [this approach](https://reactgo.com/vue-change-favicon-dynamically/) but it did not work

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will help, it is awesome libary with utilities for Vue 2 and 3.
[VueUse useFavicon](https://vueuse.org/core/useFavicon/#usefavicon)

Comment: This link is now broken. Can we get an updated one?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to grab the favicon w/ `document.querySelector("link[rel~='icon']")`.

Then, this [article](https://css-tricks.com/emojis-as-favicons/) on CSS tricks should help you achieve the result you wish.

Comment: Worked for me in a Vue 2 project. Just make sure, to grab the correct `link[rel='XXX']`, it might differ to `link[rel='shortcut icon']` or something else. Or better just use the `~=` trick that kissu suggested (codepen example has no ~).

Answer (score 0):

Great question, I'd like to toggle my favicon depending on the dark/light mode  in Vue2 with Vuetify application.

Hence path to favicon is static in index.html in Vue I think there is way around messing with index.html by selectors or CSS.

The most elegant way of doing it is using VueUse!

*The link in the correct answer above by Sebastian Wrzalek is broken please use this link for VueUse reference*

https://vueuse.org/core/usefavicon/